# #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the total of submissions,i want 2 results, 1 of submissions with specific status and 1 with all statuses:

```
SELECT submissions.campid, 
       COUNT(submissions.id) AS subsCountTotal, 
       (SELECT COUNT(submissions.id)
        FROM submissions,campaings  
        WHERE submissions.campid = campaings.id 
        AND campaings.status = 1 
        and submissions.time  >= campaings.startdate 
        and submissions.status = 10
        GROUP BY submissions.campid) AS subsCountngood 
FROM submissions, campaings 
WHERE submissions.campid = campaings.id 
AND  campaings.status = 1
and CASE 
    WHEN campaings.enddate = '0000-00-00' THEN  submissions.time  >= campaings.startdate 
    ELSE  submissions.time <= campaings.enddate
END
GROUP BY submissions.campid `
```

any help will be appreciated :)
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CASE should result in an error (or is this a MySQL specific extension)?

IMHO you just need:

```
SELECT submissions.campid, 
       COUNT(*) AS subsCountTotal, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN submissions.status = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS subsCountngood 
FROM submissions, campaings 
WHERE submissions.campid = campaings.id 
AND  campaings.status = 1
AND 
 (   submissions.time <= campaings.enddate 
  OR 
     (campaings.enddate = '0000-00-00' AND submissions.time  >= campaings.startdate)
 )
GROUP BY submissions.campid
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(submissions.id)  
FROM submissions,campaings 
WHERE submissions.campid = campaings.id AND  campaings.status = 1 and submissions.time  >= campaings.startdate and submissions.status = 10  
GROUP BY submissions.campid
```

When you grouping you may get more than one group i.e. more than one count. How you can put more than one value in the one row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT submissions.campid, 
       COUNT(submissions.id) AS subsCountTotal, 
       (SELECT COUNT(submissions.id)
        FROM submissions,campaings  
        WHERE submissions.campid = outer_camp.id 
        AND campaings.status = 1 
        and submissions.time  >= outer_camp.startdate 
        and submissions.status = 10
        GROUP BY submissions.campid) AS subsCountngood 
FROM submissions outer_sub, campaings outer_camp
WHERE submissions.campid = campaings.id 
AND  campaings.status = 1
and CASE 
    WHEN campaings.enddate = '0000-00-00' THEN  submissions.time  >= campaings.startdate 
    ELSE  submissions.time <= campaings.enddate
END
GROUP BY submissions.campid
```

You need to correlate the subquery.